# Amchart4 not shown till end of Datatime From json file in parseend event

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I looking for solution to shown all my data in amcharts4 , My data not shown exact and just sme out before them is shown , what is soltion for them ?

```
chart.dataSource.url ="/static/json/{{ Post.Datasource|safe }}.json";
chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.JSONParser();
chart.dataSource.reloadFrequency = 5000;
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "i";
  var title = chart.titles.create();
//Funtion Date From and to
chart.dataSource.events.on("parseended", function(ev) {
      var data = ev.target.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var startdate = new Date(data[0]["DATETIME"]).toISOString().replace("T"," ").replace("Z","").replace(".000","");
      var enddate = new Date(data[data.length -1]["DATETIME"]).toISOString().replace("T"," ").replace("Z","").replace(".000","");
  }
    title.html = (
        "Data from :" + '<span class="colors"> ' +
        startdate+ '</span> ' +
        " to " + '<span  class="colors">' +
        enddate + '</span>'
    );
});
```

Text shown less than exact lenght of data, also my title not refreshed

[image: but my data is more than this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moment library can convert data easy

starttime = moment(starttime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");